# how to give space between table rows

Tags: html

I have table with zebre-strip and I want to give 1cm space between two rows. This is my example : http://jsfiddle.net/6q3r8bj9/6/

```
table {width: 100%;}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #4286f4;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f49541;
}
```

Comment: Did you even tried to do it?

Comment: space like white background or like space inside the row?

Comment: white background space @JarlikStepsto

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you want. Change the `5px` in `border-spacing` to the values you desire.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 5px 5px;
  border-collapse: separate;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #4286f4;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f49541;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```